# Wix: Parsing values and storing in registry

Tags: c#, wix

I am new to WIX and have been tasked with creating an installer that does the following:
I have situation here where user are allowed to key in multiple IP's in a textbox (Type Edit) with comma (,) separated.

For ex: 192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2,192.168.1.3

How do I split this values based on comma(,) during installation and store in registry with 3 Keys (here the values would be null and only registry key will be the IP's).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know WIX does not provide any string manipulators natively to achieve this. But you can always create a custom action, pass in the properties and then write C# code within custom action to do whatever you want.

[Example for creating custom action](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jschaffe/archive/2013/01/24/10361809.aspx)